# gridview datakeys has count=0

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

`e.RowIndex` is 5 but `gridView1.DataKeys.count=0`

Can you help me?

```
protected void gridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string T10_CodGar = gridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["T10_CodGar"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from [PUMA2_FINANZIARIAFAMILIARE].[dbo].[TCOR10] where T10_CodGar=" + T10_CodGar, con);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (result == 1)
        {
            loadStores1();
            //    lblmsg.BackColor  = Color.Red;
            //    lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.White ;
            //    lblmsg.Text = stor_id + "      Deleted successfully.......    ";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: General comment: `catch (Exception ex) { }` is a horrible anti-pattern. Exceptions happen for valid reasons. Catching them and suppressing them like this just hides problems which need fixing. If you're actually _expecting_ an exception in this block for any _legitimate_ reason (not a mistake or unexpected error), then at the very least you should catch only that specific exception type, and log the exception so that it's clear what took place. Then maybe re-throw it if that's appropriate.

Comment: Re your question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx says _"When the DataKeyNames property is set, the GridView control automatically creates a DataKey object for each row in the control....The DataKey objects are then added to the control's DataKeys collection. "_ Have you set the DataKeyNames property or not? We can't tell from your code.

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewStyle" Visible="false" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
               
                OnRowEditing="gridView1_RowEditing"
                OnRowCommand="gridView1_RowCommand"
                OnRowDeleting="gridView1_RowDeleting"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="gridView1_RowCancelingEdit">

Comment: if I put the property "datakeynames" it does not display the grid

Comment: What did you put for the property value? What does "does not display" mean? I guess you get some exception or other problem? (Or maybe not - see my first comment)

Comment: thanks ADyson was missing the property
DataKeyNames

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for DataKeys at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx

says

> When the DataKeyNames property is set, the GridView control
>   automatically creates a DataKey object for each row in the
>   control....The DataKey objects are then added to the control's
>   DataKeys collection.

You need to set the DataKeyNames property on your GridView with a suitable value before this will work.